# Automatically snap lines at angles when offsetting

Tags: qgis, snapping

I used the geometry generator to offset lines.

> offset_curve($geometry,"offset")

Is there a way to get the lines automatically snapped at angles when they are connected?
I can use the rendering levels for this case, but that won't be so easy with a lot of lines.

[image]

Comment: you could clip them by a buffer of the endpoint, but that would shorten one of the lines at the other end. Like this: `offset_curve(clip($geometry,buffer(end_point($geometry),5)),"offset")` (I didn't test it, I may have used the wrong function name or syntax for `clip`.)

Comment: Sorry for the long delay to answer.
I couldn't get the clip command in QGIS.